# Duplicate modal shown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Looks like Bootstrap is generating multiple duplicate events when the `.modal('show')` function is called. I expect that a single `'shown.bs.modal'` event will be called, but rather, I get anywhere from 3-7 event logs from my single event handler.

Removing the .fade class from the `.modal` div fixes this, and the event only triggers once.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cmsDialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cmsDialog').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        console.log('modal shown!');
    });
    $('.cmsZoneToolbar').find('.cmsZoneEdit').click(function(e){
        openeditscreen();
        return false;
    });

});
openeditscreen = function() {
    $('#cmsDialog').find('.modal-body').html('MODAL CONTENT');
    $('#cmsDialog').modal('show');
}
```

JS Fiddle (Note that I could only replicate this using jQuery 1.7.1):
http://jsfiddle.net/mborn/z0zstu0o/3/

EDIT: Is updating my version of jQuery the ideal solution? There seems to be no other documented cases of this bug - and is it a jQuery bug, or a Bootstrap bug? Or is it a bug at all, am I doing something wrong? (I'm not a Bootstrap guru yet.)

Comment: If it's only happening in 1.7.1 then I would just use a newer version of jQuery. You dictate which version of jQuery is being used on your site, it doesn't vary by user.

Comment: I use Bootstrap 3 heavily on jQuery 1.8.3. I've encountered no problems. jQuery 1.9 deprecates some things you may need, so try the 1.8 branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Bootstrap `v3.0.0`, the minimum jQuery version is `1.9.0` according to their [`bower.json`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.0.0/bower.json)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">= 1.9.0"
  }
```

You can get to this from the **What's included** section of their documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included

Comment: And we also mention & link this on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-individual-compiled

Comment: You didn't technically answer my question, since I was more curious about **why** this happened than how to fix it. Still, this is a reasonable solution for the bug.